# How to use Shortcode from one WordPress page in another WordPress page?

Tags: shortcode, linking

Is there a way to use a shortcode that works in one WordPress page in another completely separate WordPress page?

Like if the shortcode was just a link, I could just use a href on the other page, but it's a shortcode [xxx] that needs to execute on the 1st Wordpress page that I want to display on another completely separate Wordpress page if that makes sense?

Comment: In case you are already using Gutenberg (and not the Classic Editor) you could put it into a reusable block.

Comment: Please elaborate. I don't understand.

Comment: Please accept the anser as correct if it helped you, see my answer below

Comment: I have just realized - what do you mean by "completely other page" - another domain (separate installation of WordPress)?

Comment: Yes, another domain.

Comment: Just lol, darnnnn

Answer (score 0):

Step 1)
Create a new shortcode in the Gutenberg editor.

[image: Step 1. Create a new shortcode block]

---

Step 2)
Enter your shortcode.

[image: Step 2. Enter your Shortcode]

---

Step 3)
Add it to reusable blocks

[image: Step 3. Add it to our collection of reusable blocks]

---

Step 4)
Give it a name

[image: Step 4. Give it a name]

---

Step 5)
Navigate to the page or post where you want to use that block again.
Call that block by typing it's name /Sta...

[image: Call our new custom block in the new place]

---

Final result

[image: ans]